# How do i map over an array with objects inside it

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been on this for at least 12 hours now. I have a function that gets called

This is where the first function is called

```
const CustomAgenda = () => {
  return <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>{returnArray()}</ScrollView>;
};
```

It calls the returnArray function below, which calls the getJobs function, that populats the 'j' array

```
const returnArray = () => {
  getJobs().then(() => {
    console.log(j);

    return j.map(x => {
      console.log('j' + j[1]);
      return (
        <View key={x.id}>
          {/*style={styles['wrapper' + x.type]}*/}
          <Text style={styles.text}> {x.itemType} </Text>
          {/*<Text style={styles.text}> {x.size} </Text>*/}
          {/*<Text style={styles.text}> {x.test} </Text>*/}
        </View>
      );
    });
  });
};


let j = [];

async function getJobs() {
  console.log(1);
  await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(global.uid)
    .get()
    .then(async documentSnapshot => {
      documentSnapshot.get('jobs');
      console.log(2);
      await getJobData(documentSnapshot.get('jobs'));
      console.log(3);
    });
}

const getJobData = async jobList => {
  for (const i of jobList) {
    let item = {};

    await firestore()
      .collection('Jobs')
      .doc(i)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        item.id = i;
        item.itemType = documentSnapshot.get('itemType');
        item.size = documentSnapshot.get('size');
        item.type = 'Pickup';
      })
      .then(() => {
        j.push(item);
      });
  }
};
```

The problem i am having is that as you can see from the output below, it console logs 'j' before the .map is called, and after. Why is it returning [object object] as opposed to the 'j' value

```
     LOG  [{"id": "fST5A2WzgUR66xxNdHAU", "itemType": "Carerre", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "cKQLGqqtyyuxhO7ZuFLR", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "l3KCfGSKh3MCySje832f", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "B8byNmHdc6g5YGqTPovX", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "FQraUtV7uTDyvkux1Vkf", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}]

 LOG  j[object Object]
 LOG  j[object Object]
 LOG  j[object Object]
 LOG  j[object Object]
 LOG  j[object Object]
```

Comment: have you tried  ```getJobs().then((j) => { ```

Comment: Observation: Your `returnArray` function doesn’t return anything.